# React router refresh in modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Im trying to open a modal with url but after refreshing the page url stays correct but modal won't open.
Here is the code example but in my project the modal is not opening absolutely, but location state: true is correct.

Comment: If you refresh the page state gets lost. It is undefined. It cannot be preserved on refresh. Only if you store it to local storage or sth similar it can be preserved

Comment: But after refresh in inspect im loging 'location' and inside state is true, how can that happen?

Comment: Hmm, as you are refreshing the page, won't you want to use componentDidMount?

Comment: Another note you shouldn't be using componentWillUpdate, see react documentation for preferred method: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: I tried to save data in localstorage but after refreshing value is loosing too. How to save ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is undefined also in the devtools

Use local storage like this:

Create a state variable to hold modal status

```
this.state = { isModalOpen: false };
```

On the Link change the local variable and save the modal status to the local storage

```
 <Link
   className="frontpage-job"
   to={"/modal/1"}
   onClick={() => {
     localStorage.setItem("isModalOpen", JSON.stringify(true));
     this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
  }}
   >
    modal
 </Link>
```

Now if you refresh when the component mounts change `isModalOpen` to true only of it is true

```
componentDidMount() {
    let isModalOpen = localStorage.getItem("isModalOpen");
    isModalOpen = JSON.parse(isModalOpen);
    if (isModalOpen) this.setState({ isModalOpen });
  }
```

Last but not least create a closeModal method to close the modal, clean the url and reset local-storage value

```
closeModal = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("isModalOpen", JSON.stringify(false));
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: false });
    this.props.history.push("/");
  };
```

Pass it as prop to modal instances

```
<Modal isModal={isModalOpen} closeModal={this.closeModal} />
```

Now if you have opened the modal and you refresh the modal remains open. If you close it and refresh it is closed

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-refresh-in-modal-xpu8g)